# Silverlight MediaElement not reporting correct DownloadProgress value in change event

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I'm using a `MediaElement` control in a Silverlight 4 island within an ASP.NET application.  The source of the `MediaElement` is a method in a WCF data service using webHttpBinding with `transferMode="streamed"`.  The method returns a `Stream`.  The media is retrieved successfully and plays back on the client.  The problem I'm encountering is in the `DownloadProgressChanged` event where I'm trying to update a progress bar during the download process.  According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), this event should fire:

> whenever the amount of total content downloaded increases by 0.05 or more (as a factor of 1.0, which indicates completion), or reaches 1.0.

This is not the behavior I'm seeing.  I'm using the following code to output the value of `DownloadProgress`:

```
private void previewMediaElement_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("progress = " + previewMediaElement.DownloadProgress);
    // Update value of a progress bar
}
```

Here's the result for a sample video:

- progress = 7.34134975033385E-15
- progress = 1.44467771079348E-14
- progress = 2.15522044655359E-14
- progress = 2.86576318231369E-14
- progress = 4.14781056723434E-14
- progress = 1

Regardless of the size of the video, the `DownloadProgress` value stays extremely small until it jumps to 1.  As the size of the video increases, the number of those extremely small values also increases.  Should this event work correctly for a streamed response?